# Is it possible to move a certain part of a mesh along all 3 axes?

Tags: rigging, transforms

So since I don't know how to make those eye rigs involving eyeballs, I'm taking an approach on 2D eye-shaped meshes (eyes and pupil. My question regards around moving the pupil mesh along an angled axis on a rig.

Blender File [image]

This is the initial location of the pupil.
[image]

This is the result of a basic move only along the x axis.(Usually the result when attempting to move the pupils on a rig.)
[image]

This is the initial idea of how I want the rig to move the pupil

[image]

Is it possible to rig the pupils to move along the x, y, and z corners within the eye location? If so, how can I make it work?

Comment: you can limit transformations on local axes. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/constraints/transform/limit_location.html

providing a blend file will be very helpful
https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

- select a face for reference direction and add new transform orientation

  - ill use the white part of eye for it
  - https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/orientation.html#custom-orientations

  [image: add transform orientation]
- move along new x direction

  - select pupil
  - `G` `X` to move along new x axis
  - `G` `X` `X` to move along global x axis

  [image: move along custom transform orientation]

  - You can also choose an orientation from the tool settings

  [image: tool settings]
- add shape keys to animate

  - https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/shape_keys/index.html
  - add a new shape key

  [image: new shape key]

  - with the shape key selected, enter edit mode, and set the new position of eye

  [image: editing shape key]

A better angle

[image: better angle]

Extra: control shape keys with rig: https://blenderartists.org/t/shape-keys-with-a-rig/669010/4

---

Comment: So it kinda works, but it only orients on one eye. When I try to do the other one, it moves on the orientation on the first eye, even when selecting on the opposite face. And other times it just doesn't orient on the faces.

Comment: you will have to create another transform orientation for the other eye @WannabeHere

Comment: Ok that seems to do the trick. But if I wanted the eyes to look up and down, would I have to apply the same principle?

Comment: yes. add new shape key and move eye along y @WannabeHere